# NullReferenceException when triggering event

Tags: c#, events, sockets, event-handling

Consider the following:

```
class Client
{
    public static event EventHandler connectFailed;

    private Socket socket;

    public Client()
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndpoint(
            IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"),
            7900
            );

        try
        {
            socket.Connect(endpoint);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            connectFailed(e, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Assume the rest of the code is implemented (Event handlers and such in Program.cs).

I am running into an issue with `NullRefrerenceException` on the `connectFailed(e, new EventArgs());` line, and I can't understand why. All my other events are firing just fine, and I don't see how this is any different.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your connectFailed += <EventHandlerMethod>;

Comment: It's in the Program.cs, and it's fully implemented.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need a null check - in C# you can't call events when there are no handlers registered on that event.

The normal thing would be to implement an OnConnectFailed method:

```
protected virtual void OnConnectFailed(e as EventArgs) {
    EventHandler tmp = connectFailed;
    if(tmp != null)
        tmp(this,e);
}
```

Also, the first argument to the event handler should be `this`, not the exception. If you need to pass the exception to the event handler, create an `EventArgs` class with an exception property.

Also, there's no point in raising an event from the constructor... nothing has a chance to add a handler to it.

Comment: The key is the last sentence, there isn't a way for a for anything to subscribe to the event before the constructor finishes.  You should probably refactor out the connect code and make it a method named Connect().

Comment: Actually, this is partially correct in the context of my application, and it gave me a breadcrumb I needed to solve the issue. I was registering the event handlers _after_ I instantiated a `Client` object, so they weren't registered. I just moved my code around and it worked after that. Thanks!

Comment: This is *not* how to fire an event. It leaves you open to race conditions should subscribers unsubscribe from the event after the null check but prior to the event invocation. It is important to understand the subtleties of events and ensure you stick to the pattern intended by the designers of the construct. See the fabulous Mr. Lippert's blog for the bigger picture... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx

Comment: Looks like VB.NET has the upper hand when it comes to events. You can just use `RaiseEvent` without worrying about it being null. But it C#, if you raise an event no one's subscribed to, it throws an error. Wtf?

Comment: Your solution is now safe from the mentioned race condition which could cause a null reference exception, but would it not be more sane to try/catch? With your current solution, someone could unsubscribe from the event but then still receive it a few cycles later. Unlikely to be a problem, but it's certainly possible that, say, data required to handle the event was destroyed right after the unsubscribe.

Comment: Hmm, should have read @spender's article first, for sure, although it doesn't change my question much. My question is now, is there a reason that try/catch isn't the perfect solution it seems to be?

edit: and while we're at it, why does VB do what I'd have expected (No handlers? No problem!) while in C# there seems to be little advantage to using events over just delegates (besides ease of multiple-subscription).

Comment: @AlexWhittemore If you use try/catch, you will hide the error if there is an exception inside the event handler. The difference with VB is just a difference in language design - though I'll note that if you don't define an On... method then it will be more difficult to change the behavior in inherited classes.

Comment: @AlexWhittemore And what do you mean "someone could unsubscribe from the event but then still receive it a few cycles later"? Events aren't multithreaded, the other code is not going to be running during that "gap". And even if it could, that problem would already exist from the low-level memory accesses, even without a temp variable.

Comment: That's a good point I think is true: if you had a null reference exception IN the event handler, it'd get hidden. But additionally, someone explained to me catching exceptions is much more expensive than the simple null comparison because if the handler IS null, you have to go through the work of creating the exception object etc etc. For things like controls where events happen very frequently and often go unhandled, that's an issue for performance.

Comment: The second race condition is where thread A, let's call it a worker, goes to fire an event and creates a temp copy. Thread B, a form, unsubscribes from A's event, but just a moment later, A sends it anyway because the copy still contains a reference to B's handler. B gets called when it didn't expect to. This can happen any time, and the generally accepted solution is "make handlers that are robust against being called when they shouldn't be."

Comment: Is this actually the solution to this questions problem? By adding this code to the class you're practically erasing the problem here, simply stopping the exception to be thrown. But the real problem still exists, the event is not handled from where the object from this class has been instanced.

Comment: @VahidNateghi I did mention at the end that there's no point in raising an event from within the constructor.

Answer (score 13):

Also in C# 6 you may do the *null checking* this way:

```
connectFailed?.Invoke(this, e);
```

Answer (score 9):

Found it,

```
public delegate void OnRequestReceivedHandler(object sender);
public event OnRequestReceivedHandler ReqeustReceived = delegate { };
```

Answer (score 1):

'connectFailed' is an event.
If nobody susbcribes to the event, it will be null, so you have to check for the null case.

To make this safe you would need a null check, i.e:

```
if (connectFailed != null)
    connectFailed(e, new EventArgs());
```

**However**, this pattern is not enough, because of multithreading. The recommended approach is this:

```
EventHandler temp = connectFailed;
if (temp != null)
    temp(e, new EventArgs());
```

This not only checks for the null condition, but also copies the event first to ensure it is thread-safe (if the event queue is changed by one thread while the event is being handled on another thread, the behaviour could be undefined. By copying it first you ensure that the subscriber list remains the same for the duration of the event-handling process)

Comment: Wrong way to fire an event. Think race condition. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx